# Upper bound for curvature of curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose, $\gamma$ is a smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\gamma$ lies inside some tangent circle $C$ to $\gamma$ at point $\gamma(0)$. I need to show, that $K_{\gamma}(0)\ge K_C$. I can solve this problem if $K'_{\gamma}(0) \neq 0$.

If $K'_{\gamma}(0)\neq 0$ there exist $\epsilon > 0$, such that $\gamma[(-\epsilon,0)]$ lies inside (outside) the osculating circle, and $\gamma[(0, \epsilon)]$ lies outside (inside).

But how to deal with it, when $K'_{\gamma}(0) = 0$?

Comment: It seems to me that, if $K'_{\gamma}(0)=0$, then the curvature at this point is either extremal or locally constant.

Comment: If what you are saying is true, i know how to solve my problem. Why $K(t)$ can not be like $t^3$?

Comment: By the same argument as yours I guess. The sign of the curvature should be the same as the second derivative of the function whose graphic representation is your curve, implying a change of sign of the curvature were this function odd.